# Move files/shares/permissions from one server to another

Tags: windows-server-2008, file-sharing

We have a Windows 2000 file server that we would like to move the file shares with permissions to a new Windows 2008 server.
I have tested the FSMT from Microsoft, and it seems that it also creates the oldservername then the shares.
Is there a better faster way of moving these shares? Robocopy is a bit confusing, as we have tested that with switches, but we have missed some.

Any suggustions?

Answer (score 4):

In the past we've used robocopy and it worked well.  It allows you to move all the data once which can take a long time, and then you can run it again a second time to grab anything that changed.  This method allowed us to move all the data over the course of a week, and then grab the changes quickly on a Saturday evening before the cut over.

Here are the robocopy commands we used:

robocopy   /copy:DATSO /mir /XD "system volume information" /XD recycler /r:0 /V /Log:robocopylog-*to*.txt

However, you asked about other utlitties and if that is still the path you'd like to take then you can always backup and restore.  Most backup and restore utilities will restore with the correct permission, but this would make for a longer downtime of the data.

Comment: robocopy is the way to go... we've used it to move nearly a 100 servers worth of data over 10 years.

Comment: +1 for recommending a backup/restore - too many people don't test backups and when migrating to a new server, this is a great reason to test.  I'll add that using a backup and restore methodology can provide for VERY LIMITED downtime if you do it right - do a full backup, restore it... then make the share read-only and do a differential backup and restore that.  Done.  ANd because most networks don't have a huge data changes, the differential ca take very little time - far less than having to wait for a robocopy to finish.